# How can I replace map() function with list comprehension or for loop?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I write this code without using map()

```
k1=list(map(float,lines[1].split(", ")[1:]))
```

Comment: `c = map(a, b)` can usually be replaced with `c = [a(i) for i in b]` if you don't care about using efficiency of generators

Comment: In fact `map` is a class not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call `float()` function over every element of `lines[1].split(", ")[1:]`

```
k1 = [float(x) for x in lines[1].split(", ")[1:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop:

```py
k1 = []
for x in lines[1].split(', ')[1:]:
    k1.append(float(x))
```